# How to determine which rows in table are not properly sorted by parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table structure:

```
table Parent (Id)

table Child (ParentId, SortOrder, Id, Data)
```

Normal data should look like this in the `Child` table:

```
ParentId    SortOrder   Id     Data
--------    ---------   ----   ----
   1            0        100   'Samuel'
   1            1        101   'Levi'
   1            2        102   'Isaac'
   2            0        103   'Emma'
   3            0        104   'Maddison'
```

Unfortunately, something has become corrupted to make the data look like this:

```
ParentId    SortOrder   Id     Data
--------    ---------   ----   ----
   1            2        100   'Samuel'
   1            4        101   'Levi'
   1            5        102   'Isaac'
   2            3        103   'Emma'
   3            0        104   'Maddison'
```

How can I identify, through SQL, parents with children that are not properly ordered through my zero-based SortOrder column?

In the above example, the SQL query would tell me that ParentId 1 and 2 are invalid.

Comment: Do you have a "correct" data source that you can compare against?

Comment: i'd bet this got "corrupted" by deleting some entries from table

Comment: @Abe: no I don't; both production & test have the same data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the generated Row_number against the recorded sortorder

```
select distinct ParentId
from 
(
select *, rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by parentid order by sortorder) -1
from Child
) X
where rn <> Sortorder
```

Comment: change `distinct ParentId` to `*` to see all mismatches